# How to reference a variable in one file, and be able to use across multiple files?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, reference

I have a question which might seem very simple and has multiple answers out there, however I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

I have an `index.html` file, which consists of this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="scalar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] *= 5
  }
alert(data)
}
</script>
</head>
```

And in the same folder, I have the `scalar.js` file which only consists of this simple line:

```
var data = [10, 20, 30, 40];
```

Now, the issue I have is that `index.html` is not using the array I defined in `scalar.js`. I have tried putting `<script src="scalar.js"></script>` in the body of the HTML file, and still no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! (Also I would like to keep the scalar.js file and not set the variable data in the index file).

UPDATE: See code here **https://github.com/amosallaei19/NEURepo**

Comment: "*`index.html` is not using the array*" - uh, you are never calling the function anywhere, and you don't output `data` either?

Comment: @Bergi please see the link to my code. I do output the value of data as an alert.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] please?

Comment: Sure. See the updated question. This should now be a working example

Comment: You have not call your function myFunction() after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your code and created another file and include in index.html.
In my case everything is working file. I modified little bit your code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="scalar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
//let data = [10, 20, 30, 40];
myFunction();
function myFunction() {
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] *= 5;
    console.log(data);
  }
}
</script>
</html>
```

it display below output

```
test.html:13 (4) [50, 20, 30, 40]
test.html:13 (4) [50, 100, 30, 40]
test.html:13 (4) [50, 100, 150, 40]
test.html:13 (4) [50, 100, 150, 200]
```

Comment: Just tested your code. For some reason, it does not work for me. I will try and upload my code for people to see what the actual problem is

Comment: I do not use console.log, I am trying to have my code alert the data variable. Give me about 5 minutes to upload my code

Comment: Please see the edited question for the link to code

Comment: Your code is working fine. I have tested. It didnt showing error.

Comment: Alright, I have found my issue. The code I copied on Github was only two files of about 5,000 I have. I found that in the index.html file, there was another reference to a JS file that blocked the use of my scalar file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In the `<script>` block, you are referencing the `data` property in the `window` global object (because there is no `data` variable declared in your function).

But the `let` statement [does not create properties of the window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let); access to the declared `data` variable is limited to the `scalar.js` file. Only `var` create properties of the window object.

Change this line from

```
let data = [10, 20, 30, 40];
```

to

```
var data = [10, 20, 30, 40];
```

Comment: OP uses a (presumably global) `data` variable, not the `window.data` property?

Comment: @Bergi In browsers, global variables declared with `var` become automatically properties of the `window` object.

Comment: Sure they do, but it doesn't matter - OP does not access them as properties of the `window` object.

Answer (score -2):

In scalar.js, you add data into window object and in html you can get data from window.

```
window.data = [10, 20, 30, 40]
```